# Vanilla JSF application with javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

Hey guys I have been trying different Javascript/AJAX jsf frameworks.  I find most of them extremely heavy.  Icefaces tends to add so much javascript just for simple things and it uses a notoriously slow javascript framework also.  Primefaces is a little better since it uses jquery but I still find it kind of heavy.  What if I just want to use straight vanilla jsf and add javascript on top of that.

What is the best way to go about this.  I would need to be able to output javascript to the page from the backing bean.  Would a servlet or restful service be good way to output javascript/html to a page?

I basically want to use basic jquery animations.  Maybe do a datatable filter.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is definitely supported in JSF. You can use the `<h:outputScript>` tags for this and additionally the `<h:outputStylesheet>` tag if you also need CSS.

With these tags you can include scripts per view (page), although you can also opt to include them for all pages by creating a master Facelets template and include those there.

You can also create very simple components of your own by using JSF/Facelet's composite component feature. Those components just consist out of a simple .xhtml template file and those can include the javascript libraries you need and contain your own lightweight tailor-made javascript.

See this for some examples of using the `<h:outputScript>` tag in JSF: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/